# Android - Save HTML 5 Canvas to png

Tags: android, html, html5-canvas

I have a webapp that uses an HTML 5 canvas to allow the user to draw.

I need to save this to the sdcard as a png.

I can get the base64 by using `.toDataURL()` but I can't figure out how to use that to save the file.

I am using Phonegap, not sure if that can be used to help.

Or maybe I could pass the data to Java and do it from there, but I'm not that familiar with Java.

Answer (score 0):

try Canvas2Image lib http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/

Comment: I have tried that but could not get it to work with Android. I did experiment with it in Chrome and it prompts the user to save and I would rather no prompt when the save button is pushed.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a similar thing: https://github.com/jimdoescode/jqScribble

Included in that repo is a PHP script for saving the base64 data as an actual image.